# I can't open localhost:8088 when I use hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

After I configured all the *.xmls file in hadoop. I use the command:

```
./sbin/start-all.sh
```

everything goes well I use jps to check the process, all of them are running.

But when I go to localhost:8088, it shows "It looks like you are making an HTTP request to a Hadoop IPC port. This is not the correct port for the web interface on this daemon." at the first time.

and if I refresh the page, it told me "No web page was found for the web address: http://localhost:8088/" ERROR 404
However, localhost:9870 is working.

If I use start-yarn.sh only, I can go to localhost:8088, it shows the content well, but if I use "start-dfs.sh", I can't open 8088 again.

I tried to format the namenode, it does not work.
If I delete the tmp folder, I can open 8088 all the time, but I can't open 9870.

I am new in hadoop and network, I can not figure out what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

- run

  netstat -tlpn

comamdn to see if another service is using port 8088

_

- after running start-all.sh, hist "jps" command to see what services
  are up.
- check logs to see if there is any problem reported.

Comment: All of the services appear in the list. But I can not open the web. it is wired that there is not port 8088 in the list...

Answer (score 0):

Using hit and trial method :-

as stated by @Aref Khandan use below command to check for port numbers ,
run `netstat -tlpn`

there will be some **local addresses** with their **state as "LISTEN"** and program name as "$SomeNumeric/java"
you can try suffixing their port numbers too to your `localhost`

In my (Hadoop 3.3.5) case , nameNode web gui was on port #`9870` , secondary name node #`9868` and nodemanager at #`9842` .
You can also refer to this link

```
https://www.stefaanlippens.net/hadoop-3-default-ports.html
```

Also verify the clusterID in both the node categories(name & data) in VERSION file.

Brute way to fix would be to take the back-up of your nodes and then deleting the nodes .
Then perform the same namenode formatting and running start-all.sh .
Hope it helps.Thanks